# Django TabularInline fields giving error on updating inline fields

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a models like

```
class Section(models.Model):
    section_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    section_tiles = models.ManyToManyField(Tile, blank=True)
    on_menu = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    section_is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Section"
        verbose_name_plural = "Sections"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.section_title



class Page(models.Model):
    page_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    page_sections = models.ManyToManyField(Section, blank=True)
    on_menu = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    page_is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Page"
        verbose_name_plural = "Pages"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.page_title
```

And at the admin part I have code such as:

```
class SectionTabularInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Page.page_sections.through

    class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        inlines = [SectionTabularInline,]

        list_display =[
        'page_title',
        'on_menu',
        ]

        list_filter =[
        'on_menu',
        ]

        search_fields = [
        'page_title',
        ]

        ordering = ['page_title']

    admin.site.register(Page, PageAdmin)
```

When I make changes in inline section of the page, Its giving an error "Please correct the errors below." without any additional information. If I remove sections from page and save it, then I can reassign them from scratch. Is there any way to change them without removing them first?

Comment: Have you found a fix/workaround?

Answer (score 0):

From: [Save M2M "Through" Inlines in Django Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872861/save-m2m-through-inlines-in-django-admin)

I found my problem: if you want many to many relationship you need to keep your original model's primary key(id).